# Ionic 2 Tab bar Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: typescript, ionic2

When i try to add tab bar in my application, he shows me a "Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Profile.html

```
 <ion-tabs>
    <ion-tab tabIcon="water" tabTitle="Water" ></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab tabIcon="leaf" tabTitle="Life" ></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab tabIcon="flame" tabTitle="Fire"></ion-tab>
 </ion-tabs>
```

Profile.ts

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

    @Component({
      templateUrl: 'build/pages/profile/profile.html'
    })
    export class ProfilePage {

      constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

      }
    }
```

system information:

```
    Cordova CLI: 5.1.1
    Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.1
    Gulp local:
    Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0-beta.31
    Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-beta.17
    OS: Windows 7
    Node Version: v0.12.7
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this got fixed at some stage and you're just using a outdated version.

1. Update app-scripts with this inside your app root directory:

`npm remove @ionic/app-scripts`

`npm install @ionic/app-scripts`

2. Update the ionic client with:

`npm remove -g ionic`

`npm install -g ionic`

3. I think not related to the issue but you should change

`templateUrl: 'build/pages/profile/profile.html'`

to

`templateUrl: 'profile.html'`